# Работа с кнопками

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Имеется две кнопки на форме. Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии, к примеру первой, нажималась вторая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вернее будет.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button2.OnClick(Button2);
end;
```

Comment: Неа, так мы попытаемся вызвать обработчик `Button2.OnClick(...)`, про который тут вообще речи нет.

Нужно просто `Button2.Click();`

Answer (score 1):

В `OnClick` первой кнопки вызываем `OnClick` второй.

```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    Button2.OnClick;
    end;

    end.
```

Comment: Не-а. точнее не совсем так.  
В вашем случае клиент получит ошибку "Not enough actual parameters", ибо  onclick - это нотифиэвент, в который надо передать параметр тип Tobject;

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно повесить обе кнопки на одно событие.
Но все таки лучше код который выполняется по нажатию кнопки 2 вынести в отдельную процедуру, и при клике вызывать процедуру.